# Pyspark crossjoin between 2 dataframes with millions of records

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes A(35 Million records) and B(30000 records)

**A**

```
|Text |
-------
| pqr  |
-------
| xyz  |
-------
```

**B**

```
|Title |
-------
| a  |
-------
| b  |
-------
| c  |
-------
```

Below dataframe C is obtained after a crossjoin between A and B.

```
c = A.crossJoin(B, on = [A.text == B.Title)
```

**C**

```
|text | Title |
---------------
| pqr  | a    |
---------------
| pqr  | b    |
---------------
| pqr  | c    |
---------------
| xyz  | a    |
---------------
| xyz  | b    |
---------------
| xyz  | c    |
---------------
```

Both the columns above are of type String.

I am performing the below operation and it results in an Spark error(Job aborted due to stage failure)

```
display(c.withColumn("Contains", when(col('text').contains(col('Title')), 1).otherwise(0)).filter(col('Contains') == 0).distinct())
```

Any suggestions on how this join needs to be done to avoid the Spark error() on the resulting operations?

[Spark error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59cjH.jpg)

Comment: Are you actually doing a cross join here?  As in no join criteria at all?

Comment: Looking at your edited question, if you are specifying join columns, you do not want a cross join. I'd suggest you test this with a **much** smaller amount of data.  If Spark is doing a full cross join on those datasets, you will end up with, if my math is correct, over 1 trillion rows.

Comment: can you paste the spark error as well in the question ?

Comment: I am interested to see if any of the records in dataframe B Title column exist as a substring in dataframe A text column. That's the reason I am doing a crossjoin. The volume is very large. I will try to use a sample and see if it helps. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using `broadcast` joins

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
c = broadcast(A).crossJoin(B)
```

If you don't need and extra column "Contains" column thne you can just filter it as

```
display(c.filter(col("text").contains(col("Title"))).distinct())
```

Answer (score 0):

Repartition the both dataframes before cross join , it will work.

Comment: Please can you [edit] to provide a small code example, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.